# iOS: How to identify date change between launches?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to update some labels of a view for different day. How could I identify whether the date has changed or not changed after the latest launch? I don't want to store the date information into core data, is there any suitable persistent store method for this purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Library folder available for your app's use.  That's where you put documents that are not user generated.  User-generated documents go in your app's Documents folder.  [This article is helpful](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/overview-of-ios-application-directories.html).

The following code from my own app fetches the path to the Documents directory.  I expect it would work to replace "@Documents" with "@Library":

```html
- (NSString*) documentDirectoryPath
{
 return [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents"];
}
```